# What is brcmfmac exactly showing me during the core check?

Tags: wifi, drivers, broadcom

I've been playing with tweaking the nvram text file for my wireless card (BCM43602 on a macbook pro).

I've found a couple wireless nvram programming references on which certain parameters (for example `maxp5ga0, maxp5ga1`), say `‘a0’ and ‘a1’ apply for Core 0 and Core 1, respectively.`

I figured this has to do with some wireless SoC that have their own processors (like on a router, for example)

But, when my laptop boots, I see the following output on brcmfmac:

```
3.200526] brcmfmac: brcmfmac_module_init No platform data available.
[    3.200537] brcmfmac: brcmf_usb_register Enter
[    3.200553] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    3.200797] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_recognition found AXI chip: BCM43602/2
[    3.201253] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_cores_check  [1 ] core 0x800:48  base 0x18000000 wrap 0x18100000
[    3.201258] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_cores_check  [2 ] core 0x812:49  base 0x18001000 wrap 0x18101000
[    3.201260] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_cores_check  [3 ] core 0x83e:7   base 0x18002000 wrap 0x18102000
[    3.201262] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_cores_check  [4 ] core 0x83c:9   base 0x18003000 wrap 0x18103000
[    3.201265] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_cores_check  [5 ] core 0x82a:8   base 0x18005000 wrap 0x18105000
[    3.201267] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_cores_check  [6 ] core 0x80e:21  base 0x18004000 wrap 0x18108000
[    3.201269] brcmfmac: brcmf_chip_cores_check  [7 ] core 0x135:0   base 0x00000000 wrap 0x18109000
```

So, what is this telling me? my wireless chip has 7 cores? that doesn't sound right, does it?